# How to use Python to auto send Outlook email on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, outlook

I would like to send outlook emails by Python on Mac OS. I downloaded and customized the code as follow,

```
def create_message_with_attachment(Contact_name, Email_address):
    subject = 'Testing Email'
    body = Contact_name + 'Auto send testing'
    to_recip = Email_address
    cc_recip = ['abc@gmail.com']

    msg = Message(subject=subject, body=body, to_recip=to_recip,cc_recip=cc_recip)

    # attach file
    Attachment1 = Path('path to attached file')
    msg.add_attachment(Attachment1)
    
    msg.show()
```

However, I can create the email, but can not send it out. Is there any function such as mag.send() to send the email?

Comment: what module do you use? What do you import? What is `Message`? `Message` can be function to generate message but you may still need modules like  [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) to send it using protocol `SMTP` or module [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) or [imapclient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/) to send it using protocol `IMAP`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show what module you use but I assumed you use
[email.message.Message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message) which is only to generate `email` but it needs other modules to connect to server and send mail.

Servers may use different `protocols` to communicate.

For protocol `SMTP` you can use standard module [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html)

For protocol `IMAP` you can use standard module [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) or simpler external module [imapclient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/) or
[imbox](https://github.com/martinrusev/imbox)